# Index for querying edges between vertices

Tags: graph-databases, janusgraph

I'm trying to check whether there is an edge between v1 and v2.

g.V(v1).outE(label).as("e").inV().hasId(v2).select("e")

Since I have too many edges on my graph, its getting slower to get a result.

I have added some indexes but it did not help. What's the suitable index to run that query faster?

Answer (score 3):

As discussed on a different question, you probably can't make that go faster as-is. You would need to use indices (and filters on those indices) around `outE()` to reduce the number of edges you are traversing to limit the amount of filters on the `inV()`.

If you have nothing to filter on besides edge label then you might consider denormalizing a bit and pushing some identifying value from the vertex to the edge and indexing that. Then it should get much faster to do your traversal because it's just this:

```
g.V(v1).outE().has('someId',v2)
```